# StringAssert.Contains("{", needle) throws System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I am using C# with .NET Core and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

When calling:

```
StringAssert.Contains(my_text, my_needle);
```

with some `my_text` values, for example:

```
StringAssert.Contains("foo bar baz", "hello");
```

a correct error message is displayed :

```
StringAssert.Contains failed. String 'foo bar baz' does not contain string 'hello'. .
   at ...
```

However, if `my_text` has other values, the following error occurs:

```
Test method MyTest threw exception: 
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
    at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.ThrowFormatError()
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at ...
```

Why is this happening?

---

Update: I have filed this as a [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/25373)

Comment: can we see the long string, is it a literal?

Comment: @MickyD I am using a simple "contains" that is not related to parsing.  Parsing is an overkill. This bug is not related to HTML. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**A quick solution was to use**:

```
StringAssert.Contains(my_text, my_needle, "", null);
```

Which works correctly!

---

Explanation: Using the debugger I have found

```
public static void Contains(string value, string substring)
```

Calls

```
public static void Contains(
      string value,
      string substring,
      string message,
      StringComparison comparisonType) {
// Calling:
        StringAssert.Contains(value, substring, message, comparisonType, StringAssert.Empty);
```

Which [calls](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/712986b05ece392cc5b086fa6f0b9018d284bad7/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Assertions/StringAssert.cs#L201):

```
public static void Contains(
      string value,
      string substring,
      string message,
      StringComparison comparisonType,
      params object[] parameters)
    {
... // calling:
        Assert.HandleFail("StringAssert.Contains", finalMessage, parameters);
```

And inside `HandleFail` the value of `parameters` is `object[]` and:

```
parameters != null ? string.Format(...) : Assert.ReplaceNulls(message)
```

triggers a call to format (since `parameters` is not `null`...).

This seems like a bug.

To reproduce:

```
StringAssert.Contains("{", "x");
```

While this works OK:

```
StringAssert.Contains("{", "x", "", null);
```

Comment: @MickyD : I have updated the answer. The bug can be reproduced using `StringAssert.Contains("{", "x");`

Comment: Why would `StringAssert.Contains` call string formatting? How is it related to HTML? `StringAssert.Contains("{", "x");` fails as well.

Comment: @MickyD : As I said, this is a bug. `string.Format` should NOT be called in this case. refer to the `null, null` call for the workaround.

Comment: @MickyD If it is not a bug, it is an "undocumented feature" ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, this error is almost always because of interpolated strings. The reason you get the error is (likely) because you have {} in your string. That's why your error has this :

> at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)

Because somewhere in your chain you will have something like string.Format() and your string having {} in it somewhere is breaking it. To get around this, you can escape them by replacing all {} with double {{}}

Comment: see my answer above.

Comment: i.e., Although the answer is "correct" - it does not help in any way to solve the described problem.  Replacing `{` with `{{` will change the strings needed to be checked by `Contains`!

Comment: How come `StringAssert.Contains("{", "x");` throwing a `System.FormatException` is not a bug? And why would replacing `"ab{cd"` to `"ab{{cd"` which would not Contain `"b{c"` help in this case?

Comment: @MickyD If `File.Open` would throw `System.FormatException` it would be a bug.  `Assert.Contains` docs' state it should raise an `AssertFailedException` exception. `{` is just a string, and should NOT be used for formatting.